# The difference betwen these two methods

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
f(z)= \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z-i)^2(z+i)^2}
$$
I need to convert this function to a *Laurent series* in the punctured neighborhood $0<|z- i|<2$ of $i\in\Bbb C$.
let $g(z) =\dfrac{1}{z+i}$: $g(z)$ can be written as power series
$$
g(z) = \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-i}{2i}\right)^n
$$
when $z$ in the said neighborhood $0<|z - i|<2$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}= -g'(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \left(\frac{-1}{2i}\right)^n(z-i)^{n-1}
$$
but when I use cauchy product, I get the following relation:
$$
\frac{1}{(z+i)^2} = g(z)^2 = -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\left(\frac{-1}{2i}\right)^n(z-i)^n
$$
**Which method is right ,and what makes the difference**?

Comment: It's the same result up to a change of variable $n \mapsto n + 1$ (and removing the useless $n = 0$ term).

Comment: It is the same, but there is a $\frac{1}{2i}$ missing at $-g'(z)$.

Comment: thanks, I found the problem : )